# Python3 - curses input/output over a network socket?

Tags: python, sockets, curses

So I've decided to learn Python and after getting a handle on the basic syntax of the language, decided to write a "practice" program that utilizes various modules.

I have a basic curses interface made already, but before I get too far I want to make sure that I can redirect standard input and output over a network connection. In effect, I want to be able to "serve" this curses application over a TCP/IP connection.

Is this possible and if so, how can I redirect the input and output of curses over a network socket?

Comment: Please show your code. Use the following code snippet to understand the socket programming. You can grab the client.py and server.py file from link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45039232/socket-programming-in-python-raising-error-socket-error-errno-10060-a-connec

Comment: There is no code that does what I'm asking about. I'm asking if it's possible to 'send' a curses interface over a network connection and how this might be done. I have a solid understanding of socket programming already, as I come from a C/C++ background and have used the Windows sockets API extensively.

Comment: May be this will helps you buddy https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7209285/is-there-a-way-to-interactively-program-a-python-curses-application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This probably won't work well.  `curses` has to know what sort of terminal (or terminal emulator, these days) it's talking to, in order to choose the appropriate control characters for working with it.  If you simply redirect stdin/stdout, it's going to have no way of knowing what's at the other end of the connection.

The normal way of doing something like this is to leave the program's stdin/stdout alone, and just run it over a remote login.  The remote access software (telnet, ssh, or whatever) will take care of identifying the remote terminal type, and letting the program know about it via environment variables.

Comment: After reading through the documentation for curses, I figured this was probably the case. I'll have to take another approach then. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a good answer here, but this is a task I've wanted to do as well, and it's NOT impossible.  But from what I've been able to tell, it's a fair amount of work unless you can find a trick.

Basically, look at how sshd or telnetd handles incoming connections and allocates a pseudo-terminal to hand off to an interactive shell.

The normal C version of curses is not thread safe, and has global state information that makes it difficult to use for this.  I noticed that python's initialization routines allow you to pass in a file descriptor, so it might be possible, but it might still fail with more than a single connection.

There was an old utility called dgamemake (I think?) that I know people have used to run nethack over TELNET directly, so that might also be worth looking at.  TELNET can provide TTYPE and NAWS negotiation, so it is possible if you can convince curses to behave, and reliably put the connection into character-by-character mode.